# Completely removing ruby from mac

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos

I have issues with building rails project, it simply says me about missing gems, while they present in system and properly configured. So whats the best way to completely remove ruby&rails from system(mac os). I already tried ways that found in google, but bug still present and i guess not all files&folders were removed from system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby and Rails are both software that is very version dependent, bringing up even worse issues than the famed "dll hell" in Windows the best way to do this is to install [RVM](https://rvm.io/), which allows you to run multiple versions of Ruby and Rails on a single system. You can then switch to the version of Ruby and Rails you need, and run/build your app.

Comment: I have rvm, and using it, and tried to remove rails&ruby via RVM, but no luck. Thats why i'm looking for other, maybe more "rude" ways to delete all files that are used by ruby or rails

Comment: My Kindle browser kept crashing trying to add a comment: You definitely don't want to replace the system ruby on a Mac. Just do find /usr *.rb to see why.  OS X is tightly coupled to the version of ruby it delivers.  Do you have RVM installed as root, or a user? It is a mistake to install it as root on OS X.  Run rvm implode to remove any trace, reinstall as a user, then look into rvmrc, which will dynamically switch your ruby and rails version just by switching into your rails project folder.

Comment: can you explain more detally about user rvm. I guess i have installed as root

Comment: when you install rvm as a user, it doesnt touch the system supplied ruby at all, it just installs ruby (and rails) in your user home.  if you also install rvmrc, each time you cd into your project folder, a script runs that auto switches the version of ruby to the one your project requires.  Links: https://rvm.io/rvm/install/ and https://rvm.io/workflow/rvmrc